# On the integral $I_s = \int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$-follow up question

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

This is a follow up on [On the integral $I_s =\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} dx$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/337897/140392)

According to the answer that i got, $I_s$ is not known to converge for any real $s<1$. But suppose $I_s$ converges for some real $s=\sigma<1$. Does it then follow that $I_s$ converges for $s=\sigma+it$ for any real $t$ ?

Comment: In fact I believe that this question, or more precisely Greg Martin's answer to it, logically precedes the quoted previous question. See my response to the previous question: it contains more detail than the accepted answer (to that question).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite: if a Dirichlet integral of this shape converges at $\sigma+it$, then it converges in the half-plane $\Re s > \sigma$, but not necessarily on the line $\Re s=\sigma$.

The proof for Dirichlet series in place of Dirichlet integrals is standard (see for example Theorem 1.1 of [Montgomery/Vaughan](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/multiplicative-number-theory-i/4E45519B26115AEEA4839C6C38206ACD). The proof should adapt easily to Dirichlet integrals.