# convergence abcissa for Mellin transforms

Tags: analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

Where can I find the theory of abcissa of convergence for integrals necessary to understand ChenClass answer to

[On the integral $I_s =\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} dx$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337897/on-the-integral-i-s-int-1-infty-pix-lixx-s-1-dx/342843#342843)

?

Note that the integral I is not a Dirichlet integral since Li is not a summatory function. In other words sI is not a Dirichlet series.

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://mathoverflow.net/q/342835/11260 , please don't post the same question twice.

Comment: I did not know the other question. My formulation is clearer I think,

Comment: It works exactly the same way [as for Dirichlet series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence), indeed $Li(x) = \sum_{2 \le n \le x} \frac1{\log n} + O(1)$  and $s \int_1^\infty (\pi(x)- \sum_{2 \le n \le x} \frac1{\log n})x^{-s-1} dx$ is a Dirichlet series. Of course once the basics are clear what we care is how it is related to and affected by the prime number theorem and the Riemann hypothesis, the abscissa of convergence being the main topic of every book on $\zeta(s)$

Comment: Would you have a book, an article to refer me to? Note that I cannot open the link underline in blue, being in China at the moment.

Comment: They are on libgen and Titchmarsh, Apostol, Montgomery and all others are on google

Comment: Thanks I did not find the info in eitherTitchmarsh or Montgomery-Vaughan, Will read Apostol (Introduction to number theory ?) carefully, Thanks for this idea of replacing Li(x) by this series, it looks promising,

Comment: The basics of abscissa of convergence of Dirichlet series are on wikipedia https://web.archive.org/web/20190814015245/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99339/discussion-between-patrick-sole-and-reuns).